# wpf - how to print a whole page to pdf with PDFSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, pdf, pdf-generation

So I want to know how to print my entire WPF page to a PDF file with PDFSharp.
I've already been looking at several articles but I can't seem to figure it out.
I want the pdf to look something like this:
[image]

I've already looked up on articles about drawing strings, lines name it. But creating every line, string and shape individually looks like a sloppy and bad idea to me.

Can anyone help me with this?

Articles will also be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Would say first export your control to image with `RenderTargetBitmap` and then use a library to export it to PDF.

Maybe this sample might help ?

http://www.techcognition.com/post/Create-PDF-File-From-WPF-Window-using-iTextsharp-1001

With this [library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Here his the Control to Image class I'm using with sucess (I'm able to get a PNG snapshot of complex UI controls implying a very deep parent-child hierarchy)

The `source` is a WPF control container (usercontrol, grid, wahtever).

The `path` is the full path for PNG output file (C:\Temp\myImage.png)

```
public class ControlToImageSnapshot
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Conversion du controle en image PNG
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">Contrôle à exporter</param>
    /// <param name="path">Destination de l'export</param>
    /// <param name="zoom">Taille désirée</param>
    public static void SnapShotPng(FrameworkElement source, string path, double zoom = 1.0)
    {
        try
        {
            var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
            if (dir != null && !Directory.Exists(dir))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dir);
            }

            RenderTargetBitmap renderTarget = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)source.ActualWidth, (int)source.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            VisualBrush sourceBrush = new VisualBrush(source);


            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();

            DrawingContext drawingContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen();

            using (drawingContext)
            {

                drawingContext.DrawRectangle(sourceBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, 0), new Point(source.ActualWidth, source.ActualHeight)));
            }
            renderTarget.Render(drawingVisual);

            PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
            encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderTarget));

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
            {
                encoder.Save(stream);
            }

            createPdfFromImage(path, @"C:\Temp\myfile.pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
    public static void createPdfFromImage(string imageFile, string pdfFile)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER.Rotate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(pdfFile, FileMode.Create));
            iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, ms).SetFullCompression();
            document.Open();

            FileStream fs = new FileStream(imageFile, FileMode.Open);
            var image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(fs);
            image.ScaleToFit(document.PageSize.Width, document.PageSize.Height);
            document.Add(image);
            document.Close();

            //open pdf file
            Process.Start("explorer.exe", pdfFile);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excidental upvote, sorry!
That code doesn't work in project, eventhough I have iTextSharp, I don't like this library so much. It gives an error at: SaveAsPng(GetImage(GridForm), sImagePath);

Comment: Well the problem then comes from the method to generate the image itself because the PDF function works just fine for me without touching a single line

Comment: See my edited answer, I've posted a full working sample of the snapshot control to PNG and then from PNG to PDF

Comment: So, in this case, you save both image file and pdf file? @Bruno

Answer (score 0):

For pdfsharp its quite easy, you can pass in an array of bytes for the pdf image and pdf, ive used this function quite a lot when dealing with images in pdfsharp.

fairly self explanatory

Open pdf and the image into a memorystream

Get pdf setup and choose page to draw on
I always set interpolate to false, I get better results with the kind of images I'm dealing with, if you have shading in your image set it to true.

then all your left to do is draw the image on the pdf and return as a memorystream

```
    public static byte[] AddImageToPdf(byte[] pdf, byte[] img, double x, double y)
    {
        using (var msPdf = new MemoryStream(pdf))
        {
            using (var msImg = new MemoryStream(img))
            {
                var image = Image.FromStream(msImg);

                var document = PdfReader.Open(msPdf);
                var page = document.Pages[0];
                var gfx = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);

                var ximg = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(image);
                ximg.Interpolate = false;

                gfx.DrawImage(
                    ximg,
                    XUnit.FromCentimeter(x),
                    XUnit.FromCentimeter(y),
                    ximg.PixelWidth * 72 / ximg.HorizontalResolution,
                    ximg.PixelHeight * 72 / ximg.HorizontalResolution);


                using (var msFinal = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    document.Save(msFinal);
                    return msFinal.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

its hardcoded for page 1 in the pdf, easily extendable to pass in pages if you want, ill leave that as an exercise for yourself, at the end you get a nice byte array containing your pdf, no files need to touch the ground enroute if you import your image as a memorystream from your control and pass it in. another answer in this topic has a good way of getting the control image.